# "input ran out of data error" popping up when I start training the dataset

Tags: keras, spyder

I was looking to run my training set. It keeps on giving the error when I try to make the model run it pops this error

> Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs batches (in this case, 12000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

```
# Convolutional Neural Network

# Importing the libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
tf.__version__

# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing

# Generating images for the Training set
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

# Generating images for the Test set
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

# Creating the Training set
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/train',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

# Creating the Test set
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

# Part 2 - Building the CNN

# Initialising the CNN
cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=[64, 64, 3]))

# Step 2 - Pooling
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))

# Step 3 - Flattening
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full Connection
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

# Step 5 - Output Layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Part 3 - Training the CNN

# Compiling the CNN
cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Training the CNN on the Training set and evaluating it on the Test set
cnn.fit_generator(training_set,
                  steps_per_epoch = 4000,
                  epochs = 3,
                  validation_data = test_set,
                  validation_steps = 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

`steps_per_epochs` notes the number of *batches* at each epoch, so actually you need to verify that you you have at least `steps_per_ecpoh * batch_size` images at your dataset (and not `steps_per_ecpoh * epochs` as you wrote). This is true both for teain and validation datasets.

A common way is to set `steps_per_ecpoh=floor(len(dataset)/batch_size)`. The `ImageDataGenerator` class has a default `batch_size` of 32, you can change it if you want by passing  a relevant parameter.